# Frontend to edit Codeigniter language files

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I have built a multilingual website with CodeIgniter using this library:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/URI_Language_Identifier/

I use it to change language in the navigation menu and the captions for some pictures. The problem is that to edit these texts I have to actually open the language file and change it there. I'd like to create an admin panel to manage these files. Is there a nice and clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option besides parsing, editing and saving the actual files, is to move the language translations from the language file to the database, then you can build the $lang array from the database inside the language file.

So your language file becomes:

```
$LANGCI =& get_instance();

$lang_query = $LANGCI->db->where('lang', 'language_x')->get('language');

foreach ($lang_query->result() as $language_data) {

    $lang[$language_data->index] = $language_data->translation;
}
```

Instead of:

```
$lang['min_size']           = 'The %s field must be at least %s.';
$lang['max_size']           = 'The %s field can not exceed %s.';
```

Then you could use normal database calls to add/edit/update the translations.

Comment: great, I was looking for something like this. I think I'm gonna try to implement it.

That piece of code with $lang['min_size'] is in a codeigniter class to manage language files?

Comment: $lang['min_size'] is just an excerpt from one of the language file from the orm package I use.  The code above would replace that as it would create $lang['min_size'] from the database results vs having it hard coded to the text file.

Comment: what orm package are you using? Just for curiosity, since I know nothing about

Comment: DataMapper - It really makes developing things alot faster and easier as it does a lot of the repetitve work for you. http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/

Comment: @Josh, with this method can we still utilize lang('key') usage in front end?

Comment: @yahyaE, yes for all intents and purposes it still functions like the built in language handling, it just populates the lang file dynamically.

Comment: @Josh, I see the point now. It is the lang file itself. /language/english/static_language.php It makes perfectly sense. Thank you,

Comment: If you do that How can covert your data to PHP variable?

Comment: @Cambodiachannel This would load when the request is made, all it does it populate the $lang array dynamically.  You'd still use the regular language library calls in your controllers.  

 `$this->lang->line('language_key');`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy to implement. Here is an example:

```
<?php

$fn = "test.txt";



if (isset($_POST['content']))

{

    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);

    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");

    fputs($fp,$content);

    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");

}

?>



<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">

    <textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Sauver"> 

</form>
```

Then just replace "test.txt" but the name of your file. If you have more than one file, it should be easy to tweak the file.

Source: http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/script-requests/2634-php-code-edit-text-file.html